# Verify user with an INT value in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am creating a button which leads to a page. But what I'm looking for is: If user X has a number 1 in the VALIDACION column, that he can access, instead if he has number 0, no. I attach a photo of the table.
How could I do this?
I really appreciate the help

[image]

Comment: Use session for this.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a function to return the validation then on the page implement it with an if statement:-

```
public function getValidacion($uid){
     $query="select `validacion` from `users` where `id`=".$uid;
     $result=$conn->query($query); 
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     return $row["validacion"].;
}
```

to implement you can :-

```
if(getValidacion($_SESSION['id'])!=0){
     //your page code
 }else{
   header("location:pagetoRedirect.php");
 }
```

your session variable must have an id value in it for this to work and be named 'id'